# Why do structs and a mutable structs have different default equality operators?

Tags: julia

I have the following code:

```
julia> struct Point
           x
           y
       end

julia> Point(1,2) == Point(1,2)
true

julia> mutable struct Points
           x
           y
       end

julia> Points(1,2) == Points(1,2)
false
```

Why are the two objects equal when it is a normal struct but not equal when it is a mutable struct?

Comment: consider updating the title of the question should be made more narrow, as you are specifically asking how `==` works by default for mutable and immutable structs.

Comment: I hear what you are saying on that, but imo, I did not know that what you suggested was really the question I was trying to ask so someone else in the same situation may not find this question given that they also don't know the right question to ask

Comment: I think it would be OK to ask the question from the original title also as a separate question and then e.g. use the answer Viral has given in the comment to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that by default `==` falls back to `===`. Now the way `===` works is (citing the documentation):

> First the types of x and y are compared. If those are identical,
>     mutable objects are compared by address in memory and immutable objects (such as numbers) 
>     are compared by contents at the bit level.

So for `Point`, which is immutable, the comparison of contents is performed (and it is identical in your case). While `Points` is mutable, so memory addresses of passed objects are compared and they are different as you have created two distinct objects.

Comment: I feel that this blog post is also a useful read on the topic (even though the syntax has changed): https://julialang.org/blog/2013/03/efficient-aggregates

Answer (score 3):

Bogumił Kamiński is correct, but you might as *why* that difference in the definition of `===` exists between mutable and immutable types. The reason is that your immutable structs `Point` are actually indistinguishable. Since they can't change, their values will always be the same, and so they might as well be two names for the same object. Therefore, In the language they are defined by only their value.

In contrast, for mutabke structs there are at least two ways you can distinguish them. First, since mutable structs can't usually be stack allocated, they have a memory location, and you can compare the memory location of the two mutable structs and see they are different. Second, you can simply mutate one of them, and see that only one object changes whereas the other doesn't.

So, the reason for the difference in the definition of `===` is that two identitcal mutable structs can be distinguished, but two immutable ones cannot.