# Equality testing of composite-type objects containing vectors doesn't work as expected. How to compare them?

Tags: julia, equality, composite-types

I make a custom composite type (or structure), make two objects of that type, and test if they're equal:

```
struct mytype
    stuff::Int64
end

a = mytype(5)
b = mytype(5)

a == b
true
```

This works as I expected. However, if we make the contents a vector instead, comparing `a` and `b` returns false:

```
struct mytype2
    stuff::Vector{Int64}
end

a = mytype2([5])
b = mytype2([5])

a == b
false

a === b
false

isequal(a, b)
false
```

Any idea why this is? Is there a way to compare `a` and `b` in the second case, when they contain a vector?

Comment: The answer is pretty much the same as the one to https://stackoverflow.com/q/59274263/8127 (even though the question is different: here the struct itself is immutable, but its content is a mutable `Vector`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in (meaning you can't add methods) function `===` compares mutable structs by address and immutable structs by content. `a === b` is `false` because your immutable `a` and `b` contain two different arrays' addresses, so their contents are different. `a.stuff === b.stuff` is `false` because the arrays are separate with their own addresses.

Then there is `==`, a function that you CAN add methods to. By default, it falls back to `===`, and the question "should `==` be recursive by default" is still an [open issue for Julia v2 (4648)](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4648). For now, it's expected that you write your own `==` methods for your own types. In fact, `a.stuff == b.stuff` is `true` because there are `==` methods specifically for `Array`s of `Number`s. So the simplest way for your type would be:

```
Base.:(==)(a::mytype2, b::mytype2) = a.stuff == b.stuff
```

In practice, your composite type probably has more fields so writing this stuff gets tedious. Issue 4648 includes a post (Jan 15 2021) of a generated function `structEqual` that does `==` on all fields of a struct, though I personally haven't tried it out.